# Linq query that keeps reference to nested collection in which item was found

Tags: c#, linq

I have a structure something like this:

```
class Action 
{
    uint ActionId;
}

class Trigger
{
    public List<Action> Actions;
}

class Sequence
{
    public List<Trigger> Triggers;
}
```

I need to obtain an Action with some ActionId, but also retain a reference to the Trigger that contains it. Essentially the following:

```
foreach (Trigger checkTrigger in Triggers)
{
    foreach (Action checkAction in checkTrigger.Action)
    {
        if (checkAction.ActionId == actionId)
        {
            action = checkAction;
            trigger = checkTrigger;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (null != action) break;
}
```

Obtaining just the action is simple enough:

```
Action action = Triggers
                    .SelectMany(t => t.Actions)
                    .FirstOrDefault(a => a.ActionId == actionId);
```

But how would I obtain the trigger that contains it? Clearly not similarly to the above, since it's combining the Actions lists into a single collection before searching through it.

Answer (score 0):

The Action and Trigger values obtain together in the anonymous type:

```
var actionAndTrigger = (from t in sequence.Triggers
                        from a in t.Actions
                        where a.ActionId == actionId
                        select new { Trigger = t, Action = a })
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

If an anonymous type is not suitable - for example, you need to pass data to another method - you should create a class with two properties and use it:

```
class ActionTrigger
{
    public Action Action { get; set; }
    public Trigger Trigger { get; set; }
}

var actionAndTrigger = (from t in sequence.Triggers
                        from a in t.Actions
                        where a.ActionId == actionId
                        select new ActionTrigger { Action = a, Trigger = t })
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

You can use Tuple instead of introducing an extra class:

```
var actionAndTrigger = (from t in sequence.Triggers
                        from a in t.Actions
                        where a.ActionId == actionId
                        select Tuple.Create(t, a))
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do this without the anonymous type? Say by assigning to a previously declared variable?

Comment: @FlintZA - Create your own class with two properties and use it instead. Another way - use `Tuple<T, T>`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Please add more details, since code-only and try-this answers should explain the reason they address the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two queries to extract separately the `Trigger` and the `ActionId` as the follows:

```
var trig = seq.Triggers.First(x => x.Actions.Any(y => y.ActionId == actionId));
var act = seq.Triggers.Select(x => x.Actions.Any(y => y.ActionId == actionId)).First();
```